# How to disable a parameter based on a value of another parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I would like to disable a parameter based on a value of another parameter.
[image]

My example, when the ENABLE_NEXUS = true, I would like to disable the ZIP_FILE parameter.
also when ENABLE_NEXUS = false, the ARTIFACT_NAME have to be disabled.

Any way to do this?

Thanks